# How to switch between Session 2012-13, 2013-14..and so on in mysql and php?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a page in php and mysql that opens data related to 2012-2013 if I select session 2012-2013. and if I select session 2013-2014 it should select another database related to 2013-14. can it be possible?
A company can have many years of data so how to select them by sessions?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Add date/timestamps to your database tables, then do selective queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes of course!
on the page you select the session by using any type of INPUT method like a dropdown box.

on the next page where the database has to be opened use the
**if-else** structure to choose the database name and then use mysql_select_db($sessionname).

sample code is as under:

on first page where you select session.

```
  <select name="mysession">   
     <option value="ses1213" selected>Session 12-13</option>            
     <option value="ses1314" selected>Session 13-14</option>   
  </select>
```

on next page write following PHP line while selecting database you want to open.

```
  mysql_select_db($_POST["mysession"]);
```

here i assume that the ses1213, ses1314 are the names of databases in mysql.

Comment: Thanks a lot @adeel iqbal, I got it, I have about 72 pages in a project which connect with database, so can every page understand the above query "mysql_select_db($_POST["mysession"]);"